# Resizing RGBA bitmap images stored in C as bytes array

Tags: c, bitmap, rgba

I have images stored as raw RGBA bitmaps in C. I am using:

```
unsigned char *rgbaData 
size_t rgbaDataLength; 
size_t width; 
size_t height;
```

And now I consider how should I rescale it (resize it) to obtain from current **width/height -> new_width/new_height**.

I need to write function like this prototype:

```
int rgbaResize(const unsigned char *rgbaData, const size_t rgbaDataLength, 
const size_t width, const_size_t height, const size_t newWidth, 
const size_t newHeight, unsigned char **newRgbaData, size_t *newRgbaDataLength);
```

I mean about something like this, but cross-platform solution or user implementation:

```
let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo.rawValue)

CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh)

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height))), cgImage)

let scaledImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context).flatMap { UIImage(CGImage: $0) }
```

It can be done by some free, open source and light cross-platform library?

Comment: Google for "image resize algorithm". Lots available on the net.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: rgbaResize() function how to implement, or algorithm of rasizing rgba up/down

Comment: Bilinear Interpolation is what you may want. Be aware, there are a plethora of different ways to resize an image. Some are plainly intuitive and quite small/simple to code, others use cubic-splines to blend between the values of multiple pixels in order to provide smooth up-sized images.

Comment: if you can find a fft library then it's also a good way to go

Comment: how this problem is typically solved by most libraries like .NET, Cocoa, Java? where there are functions to set size of bitmap?